# Show tabs with a different character (Emacs)

Tags: configuration, emacs, tabs, character

I'd be happy to have very soft character ">>" instead of white-space, like this:

[Mono develop http://primates.ximian.com/~miguel/pictures/Valabinding-classpad.png](http://primates.ximian.com/~miguel/pictures/Valabinding-classpad.png)

How can I achieve that in Emacs?

Comment: My advice: Don't use tabs.  Make you tab key do spaces, and convert any tabs to spaces when a source file is read in.

Comment: Not to be rude, but read the OP's name as elmacro. And I was thinking, hmm, you should already know these simple things ;-)

Comment: Some projects use tabs. Some use space. I don't care much, but I think tabs are fine if used correctly only in the BOL.

Comment: Fun fact: hitting TAB in emacs doesn't insert the TAB character-- it runs the function forward-button instead

Comment: if you're going to give advice, you need to provide some logical explanation or reason. blanket statements like "don't use tabs" are kind of useless if not qualified with some argument.

Comment: I also generally prefer to not use tabs. But sometimes it’s not up to oneself. The project one is working in might require tabs. Case in point: All projects written in Go.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**EDIT:** Just realized that blank-mode is superseded by [whitespace](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/WhiteSpace). Load this and customize `whitespace-style` to at least contain `tabs` and `tabs-mark`. I currently have:

```
(setq whitespace-style '(trailing tabs newline tab-mark newline-mark))
```

There is also [blank-mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BlankMode) which allows you to achive what you want and it gives you some nice functions to cleanup the whitespace to your likings:
http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BlankMode

Comment: right, it seems I just need to customize it slightly. Thanks, I forgot about it :)

Answer (score 31):

On my Emacs version (24.3) no additional modules are needed. It's enough to launch

```
M-x whitespace-mode
```

To customize go to `whitespace-style` variable help,

```
C-h C-h v whitespace-style
```

This mode has many functionalities. To made it simpler one may choose not to use `Face visualization'.

Comment: For further info one might consider http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/whitespace-mode.html

Comment: `M-x whitespace-visual-mode` here (XEmacs), and `customize-face whitespace-visual-tab-face` to have a special color. How would I have that automatically activated ?

Answer (score 7):

Use "M-:" (M-x eval-expression) and enter the following expression:

```
(let ((d (make-display-table)))
  (aset d 9 (vector ?> ?>))
  (set-window-display-table nil d))
```

To get back to normal enter:

```
(set-window-display-table nil nil)
```

Comment: would it be possible to also do this with a couple of whitespace characters? Such as 4 consecutive whitespaces would be transformed?

Answer (score 3):

Google search brought up [show whitespace-mode](http://aurelien.tisne.free.fr/emacs-pages/emacs/show-whitespace-mode.html). Haven't tried it myself.

Comment: eh.. I explicitly says a _character_ instead of whitespace. I knew about having colors and fancy things, so -1. But thanks anyway :)

Comment: I was only trying to help, didn't know I was giving a test. -1 for you too not trying hard to find an answer before asking.

Comment: ok fair enough, it seems you were right! :)  (according to the answer I validated) +1 back. I know whitespace mode, and I know google too. Thanks...