# How to display indentation guides in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, indentation

I'm trying to switch to Emacs as my primary source-code editor. I really miss one thing (common in even much simpler editors) - indentation guides (unobtrusive vertical lines which show the indentation level). Is Emacs able to display them?

Comment: It's helpful while reading some code.

Comment: As it happens, indentation guides would be really useful when editing Lisp code.

Comment: @user181548 more information equals less mistakes. on vim i use `set listchars=tab:░\ ` (char before the "\" is a block char that will not show up here i think, can be replaced by "|" and still looks good. after the "\" is a space character)

Comment: I am surprised that in 5 years no one has mentioned the `vline.el`:  http://emacswiki.org/emacs/VlineMode or a modification thereof such as Highlight Current Column http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HighlightCurrentColumn or CrossHair Higlighting http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CrosshairHighlighting Users may wish to implement their own modification to change colors (foreground or background) when point is on a particular column -- e.g., that matches up with the `tab-stop-list`; or odds; evens; post fill-column; or point is on any wrapped line after the first visual line, or at right window edge.

Comment: Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56144459/1879269) for a recent answer. There is a mode available on Melpa that does it. Current accepted answer dates back in 2010. This question is the first result on Google when searching "Emacs show indentation".

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There now is a mode called [highlight-indent-guides](https://github.com/DarthFennec/highlight-indent-guides) which seems to work quite well.

Comment: Very nice mode. More recent and in Melpa. Should be the new accepted answer!

Comment: Doesn't work well with Emacs 29: Is actually slower when used together with a tree-sitter mode, coloring of indent-guides doesn't work any longer as intended

Answer (score 90):

I've made a function `highlight-indentation` for this purpose, [code is on github](https://github.com/antonj/Highlight-Indentation-for-Emacs/blob/master/highlight-indentation.el).

When invoking `highlight-indentation` without a prefix argument the current indentation level is naively guessed from major mode (python, ruby and languages based on cc-mode). Only works for space indentations. Customize `highlight-indent-face` to change appearance of indentation lines.

Examples (ruby, python):
[image: Ruby, Python example]

I also frequently use this snippet that folds all code on an indentation level greater than the current line. It's a great way of getting a quick overview of the outline.

```
(defun aj-toggle-fold ()
  "Toggle fold all lines larger than indentation on current line"
  (interactive)
  (let ((col 1))
    (save-excursion
      (back-to-indentation)
      (setq col (+ 1 (current-column)))
      (set-selective-display
       (if selective-display nil (or col 1))))))
(global-set-key [(M C i)] 'aj-toggle-fold)
```

Comment: To automatically load this for JavaScript and Python files, I added the following to my .emacs: `(require 'highlight-indentation)
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'highlight-indentation-mode)
(add-hook 'js2-mode-hook 'highlight-indentation-mode)`

Comment: Hi, I've added this to my .emacs, but doesn't seem my python files look the same as on screen. I don't see any indention lines as in your example. could you advice?

Comment: +1 for the toggle-fold.  Note to others, if you enable `highlight-indentation-mode` and don't see anything, it's probably because you're using *tabs*.

Comment: Sorry for taking ages (literally) to accept your answer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I couldn't see it either. The problem is that fringe has a very light background colour in my light colour scheme and was basically invisible. I changed to header-line which was much better.

Comment: This is great... but is it possible to make it appear just as a line or something more like a the fringe dots?

Comment: Setting the font of highlight-indentation-face to Arial makes the vertical lines thinner:   `(set-face-font 'highlight-indentation-face "Arial")`
   `(set-face-background 'highlight-indentation-face "#E0E0E0")`
   `(set-face-attribute 'highlight-indentation-face nil :height 54)`

Comment: @NealYoung This is a must.

Comment: @NealYoung Though, I see some small (yellow in my face) from the cursor color being draw over it when going up with a region over this. It should be redrawn to the old when cursor leaves this indent spot. Any idea?

Comment: @PascalvKooten, not addressing your question, but if you use linum mode the suggestion in my comment messes it up.  Here is a fix: `(let ((font "Arial")        (background "#CCC")        (height 44))    (elpy-enable)     (set-face-background 'highlight-indentation-face background)    (set-face-attribute 'highlight-indentation-face nil :height height)    (set-face-attribute 'linum nil :height 1)    (set-face-attribute 'linum nil :font font)    ))`

Answer (score 5):

to my knowledge nobody has implemented indentation guides for Emacs so far. The closest thing you can get are visualization of TABs with the whitespace package, see [Show tabs with a different character (Emacs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/568885/show-tabs-with-a-different-character-emacs).

Comment: Note you can visualize spaces, too: `M-x customize-variable RET whitespace-space` then `M-x customize-variable RET whitespace-style` and add these two tokens to the Lisp expression: `spaces spaces-mark`. Eg my `whitespace-style` currently looks like this: `'(tabs trailing lines-tail space-before-tab newline indentation empty space-after-tab tab-mark spaces space-mark)`

Comment: @NoahSussman the `customize-variable` have no such a variable o.o

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you could bend [ColumnMarker](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ColumnMarker) to your needs but it will highlight a column
not givin you a single pixel.

I indent with 8 spaces so i have never thought about it  ;P

Comment: please tell more