# Display consecutive whitespace as dots in Emacs

Tags: emacs, whitespace

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/568921/1575066) nicely provides a way to display characters rather than tabs (in the example it suggests `">"`, but I confirmed it works for ".").

It uses setting the active window display table to do it.

Now my goal is to display 4 spaces as 4 dots. Using the `font-face` and a regular expression, I am confident that I can display it nicely. I am aware that I could have Emacs automatically use tab characters rather than whitespaces, but I always prefer to have whitespace characters in my files.

I've also looked at whitespace mode, but I tweaked many parameters and in the end I never get the simple dots (with a face that makes it a little less "jump" out).

So: how can I, rather than display tab characters as dots, display 4 spaces elegantly as dots in Emacs?

Comment: Let me guess: you're a Python guy, right? Talking abound 4 spaces and elegance:)

Comment: Haha, that made me laugh. Python is indeed the one I would need it for !

Comment: So you want little dots for spaces only when there's 4 of them?

Comment: The indentation really, so yea, 4 or more spaces.

Comment: Start with this: `(setq whitespace-space-regexp "\\( \\{4,\\}\\)")`

Comment: @abo-abo Nothing shows up yet... (`whitespace-mode` is enabled)

Comment: You need to revert buffer after that.

Answer (score 2):

OK, here's how to mark 4 or more spaces at beginning of line

```
(setq whitespace-space-regexp "^\\( \\{4,\\}\\)")
```

And here's how to get rid of the centered dot character for space:

```
(setq whitespace-display-mappings
  '((space-mark   ?\     [?\ ]     [?.])
    (space-mark   ?\xA0  [?\ ]     [?_])
    (newline-mark ?\n    [?$ ?\n])
    (tab-mark     ?\t    [?\u00BB ?\t] [?\\ ?\t])))
```

The changes take effect not immediately but when you `revert-buffer` or
close it and open again with customizations above already set.

Comment: Nothing happened? I put it in init file and restarted Emacs.

Comment: Works for me with `emacs -q` and evaling the code above. 4+ spaces show up as light yellow in Python, while 3 spaces do not. Works on 24.3

Comment: even with `emacs -q` it does not show up, something weird is going on?

Comment: What's your emacs version?

Comment: Emacs version: 24.2.1